# Number of permutations with condition on cumulative sum

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

We have n numbers equal to $\ln(2)$ and $m=\lceil \ln(2) \cdot n\rceil$ numbers equal to $-1$, thus $n+m$ numbers in total which are put as a sequence.

How many unique combinations we get, having the condition that cumulative sum, when adding from left to right, is allowed to be negative only at the last position?

An example: $n=4$, $m=3$:
$$
\ln(2), \ln(2),-1,\ln(2),\ln(2),-1,-1
$$
is counted since the cum-sum turns negative at the last position.
Another one:
$$
\ln(2), \ln(2),-1,-1,\ln(2),\ln(2),-1
$$
is not counted, since the cumulative sum turns negative at position 4.

I wonder if there is a closed-form expression for number of combinations depending on $n$?

Comment: In LaTeX, use \ln to make it pretty.
Equivalently, you are looking for lattice paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, m)$ that lie below the line through the origin of slope $\ln(2)$ (except at their endpoint).  I recently saw a talk by Francois Bergeron that was closely related: the slides and video are available here https://sites.google.com/view/combinatorial-enumeration/schedule

Comment: This paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08412 promised a forthcoming article about the irrational case; the two authors have written a bunch of papers together since then, it's not clear to me if any of them corresponds to the promised work.